# Google App Engine adding Deferred Task to queue spawns multiple tasks

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Lately I have been noticing that when I reschedule a deferred task, the task spawns into two or more of the exact same task. I just had a job that spawned into 4 identical tasks. We use code like the following to reschedule our tasks :

```
Queue q = null; 
if (queueName == null) 
  q = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue(); 
else 
  q = QueueFactory.getQueue(queueName); 

TaskOptions to = TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(this); 
q.add(to);
```

This code is very simple but its causing a lot of problems for our application. We have even tried giving the task a name, such as :

```
to.taskName(TASK_NAME);
```

to prevent duplicate tasks from spawning with no avail. Has anyone else seen this issue or have a solution to prevent the duplication.

Comment: Why are you rescheduling deferred tasks? If you are doing that in a task handler, multiple tasks could be created since it is possible for the same task to be run more than once.

Comment: An example of why you would why I reschedule.  Lets say I am processing a user's document in a task.  The task is running on a Frontend instance so I must abide by the 10 minute timer.  To maintain the current state of the task I need to reschedule that task to finish its job once I get close to the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

The task queue may execute the same task multiple times. This is expected behaviour.

Your task must be idempotent for it to work with task queue. i.e. if it's run multiple time it must behave as if it runs once.  Otherwise, you can't use task queue.